# Can I execute a setValue function from an imported function using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am modularizing some of my work and looking to drop some of my functions into a different `js` file in my working directory so I can trim down my `App.js`. I don't want to use redux because it's unnecessary here and I am learning hooks at the moment.

Is it possible to affect my state in a functional component in `App.js` using an imported function? Normally with class components i have used something like `context` to affect state but not sure if this is applicable with hooks. At the moment I get the error `setViewPort is not defined in Util.js` which makes sense.

Also if this isn't recommended that would be good to know. Below are snippets of my code:

**App.js**

```
import { sortArrayofObjects, getCurrentLocation } from './util';
...
  const [viewPort, setViewPort] = useState({
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100vw",
    latitude: 40.7510,
    longitude: -73.9688,
    zoom: 11
  })
...
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
       <button onClick={getCurrentLocation}>getLocation</button>
```

**Util.js**

```
  //GET USER LOCATION
  export const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    console.log("attempting to get user location ...")
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {

      console.log('user is at', [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);

      let newViewPort = {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        zoom: 14
      };
      setViewPort(newViewPort)
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can pass `setViewPort` into `getCurrentLocation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass the setViewPort function to your getcurrentLocation since getCurrentLocation it's at a different scope. So the code will be like this..

```
<button onClick={() =>  getCurrentLocation(setViewPort)}>getLocation</button>
```

then

```
export const getCurrentLocation = async (setViewPort) => {

    console.log("attempting to get user location ...")
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {

    console.log('user is at', [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);

    let newViewPort = {
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        zoom: 14
     };
     setViewPort(newViewPort)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to affect my state in a functional component in App.js using an imported function?

Yes, if that other function is a hook, or you pass it a setter from the `useState` hook for your component.

In your example, for instance, you could pass `setViewPort` to `getCurrentLocation`:

```
<button onClick={() => getCurrentLocation(setViewPort)}>getLocation</button>
```

and

```
export const getCurrentLocation = async (setViewPort) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    // ...
};
```

---

A couple of side notes:

1. Don't use `async` functions directly as event handlers. Nothing in the event system is going to do anything with the promise that all `async` functions return. (But if you really want to, just make sure that the function never rejects its promise — the DOM event system will ignore the promise it returns.)
2. Your `getCurrentLocation` function never uses `await`, so there's no reason for it to be an `async` function. Yes, it does its work asynchronously, but it doesn't consume any promises via `await`.